# Magento 1.9 shipping module help

Tags: magento-1.9

Need some help figuring out a major shipping problem. We have a site running on Magento 1.9x and we sell automotive parts. Due to the nature of the business we need some major functionality in order to be competitive and cannot figure out how to make the required shipping feature work. One required feature for us was dimensional shipping since some parts can be quite big but light weight (body plastic trim parts, spoilers etc) and we need a solution that would have accurate live rate shipping and found a good solution using AuctionInc shipping module. Our next biggest issue is free shipping: We basically break down the products into 2-3 categories: parts that can be shipped from our vendors warehouse for free in the US (lower 48) if the total cart is at least $150 and max weight is 15lb. Then there are parts that always ship from our warehouse so customers should only see live rate for those. Then there are specific products such as hazardous material (liquids, oils, chemicals) that can only be shipped in the US via Ground, no International shipping allowed.
We thought we could achieve this with shopping cart rules but found out it is not possible. For example I created a rule that if cart total is min $150 and products are from "vendor1" shipping would be free in the lower 48 states. After testing I saw that if I put a product from this vendor1 in the cart sure thing free shipping shows up, as well as additional shipping options (FedEx or faster shipping methods) which is great. But as soon as I add another product not from vendor1 which requires customers to pay for shipping, it does not work. The cart just keep showing free shipping for everything. I have looked at every possible modules and extensions on the market for Magento but cannot find a solution on how to solve these issues. Is there any way to make this work with Magento or are we pretty much dead in the water? We're desperate at this point to find a solution, any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Magento SE. One tip to increase your chances to get help: You can format your questions. Add some paragraphs and maybe bullet points. A wall of text that describes a technical problem is really hard to read.

Answer (score 1):

Matrix Rates might be your solution - in a way. http://webshopapps.com/us/magento-1-extensions/wsa-standalone/matrixrate-shipping-extension.html

The free version works just fine for us.

It will allow you to set rates for specific weights and states.

For example. I use odd weight on specific items to get a unique rate. EG 1.2222lbs has only one shipping method and it costs $3.95 - another set of items all weight 5.7123lbs and there's only "In Store Pick Up" for those items. It's kind of a pain, but it does allow a lot of flexibility

If you would still like to use the rates from FedEx etc,. use dimension weights. For example, I have a large item 80x27x8 - the actual weight is 12lbs, but it's dimension weight is 125lbs, so in the store, I have that item as weighing 135lbs. I also set max weights for shippers so an item with a dimensional weight higher than the FedEx or USPS max weight doesn't show in the checkout.

In your shipping rules, make sure the "free shipping" is "For matching items only" and discard subsequent rules, if you need to.

I know the Cat price rules can be a real PITA. Sometimes, it's the order in which you put the conditions impacts the actual implementation of the rule. For us, it had to be manufacturer/category/price if we used a different order, the rule wouldn't work. It was very frustrating to figure out the correct sequence to get the rule to work.

Hope that helps some or at least gets you in a better direction.

Comment: Thanks for the reply unfortunately webshopapps/shipperhq is probably the worse software company I've worked with. We just did a 30 day trial and spent countless hours on the phone and they cannot get anything to work not even a simple rule and they want $100/month, really?? First they said oh this is easy it will take us 1 hour to configure the rules. Guess what it doesn't work. They can do the basic rule to allow specific brand or vendor to ship for free over $150 in the lower 48 states, but as soon as you add anything else that does not ship for free to the cart, it all breaks.

Comment: webshop matrixrates, not the ShipperHQ version. The MatrixRate is free didn't know there were more versions - look at this one https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/webshopapps-matrixrate-1-multiple-table-rates-extension-1.html and then look into the code if you need some specific changes